# Prefetch data with React Router 4

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to migrate to v4 of React Router and I'm stuck with the prefetch data. The latests versions we used to have [match](http://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/match.html) function.

One of the returning parameters was renderProps but now I can't use match so I don't know how to prefetch data. The [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering/data-loading) shows how to load data but doesn't works for me because I'm using the new version of [react-router-redux](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) to sync the store.

Here's the code the client:

```
return (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={letgoMuiTheme}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <IntlProvider>
        { routes(history, store) }
      </IntlProvider>
  </Provider>
</MuiThemeProvider>
);
```

Routes:

```
export default function routes(history) {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/:lang/chat" component={Chat} />
        ...
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} status={404} />
      </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
}
```

Server:

```
if (context.url) {
  res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
} else {
  const render = () => {
    const body = renderToString(
      <StaticRouter
        location={req.url}
        context={context}
      >
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <IntlProvider>
              { routes(history, store) }
            </IntlProvider>
          </Provider>
        </MuiThemeProvider>,
      </StaticRouter>
    );

    res.setHeader('content-language', locale);
    res.render('index', {
      head,
      body,
      locale,
      state: stringState,
      ...
    });
  };

  Promise.all(
    prefetchData(renderProps, store),
  )
  .then(render)
  .catch(prefetchError => next(prefetchError));
}
```

That's my old server file:

```
    match({ history, routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      } else if (redirectLocation) {
        res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
      } else if (renderProps) {
        // Render react components once store is initializaed and return HTTP response
        const render = () => {
          const body = renderToString(
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
              <Provider store={store}>
                <IntlProvider>
                  <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
                </IntlProvider>
              </Provider>
            </MuiThemeProvider>,
          );

          res.setHeader('content-language', locale);
          res.render('index', {
            head,
            newrelicScript,
            body,
            locale,
            state: stringState,
            ...
          });
        };

        // Fetch components data and render HTML (no matter the fetch results
        // we need to render something)
        Promise.all(
          prefetchData(renderProps, store),
        )
        .then(render)
        .catch(prefetchError => next(prefetchError));
      } else {
        logger.warning('Ops !!! We should never arrive here :(');
        next();
      }
    });
```

And prefetch data:

```
export const prefetchData = (renderProps, store) => {
  const { components, params } = renderProps;
  const { dispatch } = store;
  const state = store.getState();
  const extractWrappedComponent = (component) => {
    if (component.WrappedComponent) {
      return extractWrappedComponent(component.WrappedComponent);
    }
    return component;
  };

  return components
    .filter(component => component !== undefined)
    // Get component, be aware if they are wrapped by redux connect or intl.
    .map(component => extractWrappedComponent(component))
    // Get the fetchData method of each component
    .map(component => component.fetchData)
    .filter(fetchData => fetchData !== undefined)
    // Invoke each fetchData to initialize the redux state.
    .map(fetchData => fetchData(state, dispatch, params));
};
```

Comment: Did you find solution? It's really stupid! I have a same problem.

Comment: @DarynK. I have answered my question with the solution. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking into it, I found a solution that works for me. This is the helper (before was prefetchData). `matchPath` is from `react-router-dom`.

```
export const getRouteData = (routesArray, url, store) => {
  const { dispatch } = store;
  const state = store.getState();
  const extractWrappedComponent = (component) => {
    if (component.WrappedComponent) {
      return extractWrappedComponent(component.WrappedComponent);
    }
    return component;
  };

  return routesArray.map((route) => {
    const component = route.component;
    const extractedComponent = extractWrappedComponent(component);
    const match = matchPath(url, { path: route.path, exact: route.exact, strict: false });

    if (match) {
      if (extractedComponent.fetchData !== undefined) {
        extractedComponent.fetchData(state, dispatch, match.params);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Then I call it:

```
getRouteData(routes, req.url, store);
```

Were routes is a [static routes](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering):

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: App
  },
  {
    path: '/:lang/chat',
    component: Chat
  }
  ...
```

My server file now does not have match. Instead:

```
if (context.url) {
  res.redirect(302, context.url);
} else {
  const render = () => {
    const body = renderApp(req, muiTheme, store, history, context);

    res.render('index', {
      head,
      body,
      locale,
      ...
    });
  };

  Promise.all(
    getRouteData(routes, req.url, store),
  )
  .then(render)
  .catch(prefetchError => next(prefetchError));
```

RenderApp file (Client has to be the same without `StaticRouter`):

```
const renderApp = (req, muiTheme, store, history, context) => {
  const app = (
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <IntlProvider>
          <StaticRouter
            location={req.url}
            context={context}
          >
            { appRoutes(history) }
          </StaticRouter>
        </IntlProvider>
      </Provider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );

  return renderToString(app);
};
```

appRoutes file:

```
export default function appRoutes(history) {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        {routes.map((route, key) => (
          <Route key={key} {...route} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: is there a way to call fetchdata from the subcomponents which are included in the main component?

Comment: I did not found any repo's doing tat, using redux-saga i can achieve it. But i did not find any way to parse the sub component and fetch the data.